# Moderator "move comments to chat" is failing

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools

On [this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167583/does-a-will-o-wisp-need-to-use-the-hide-action-after-turning-invisible-to-be-hi) the moderator option to move comments to chat is failing, saying that they have already been moved. Yet, the comments haven't been moved and no chatroom has even been created as far as I can tell.

I've confirmed with a co-moderator that they also can't move the messages and get the same error and that nobody can see a comment with the chatroom listed (no even when deleted comments are viewed).

I've tested on another question and it appears I was able to move those comments to chat like normal, so the bug doesn't apply everywhere it seems and may be a rare/one-off thing.

[image: Open moderator tools, with "Move comments to chat" and "Also delete the moved comments from the post" selected, and an error message "Comments from this post have already been copied to chat previously."]

Update: after a few months, I tried again and the move worked.

Comment: *mumble mumble* caching....

Comment: The timeline doesn't have an entry for "Mod moved comments to chat" which is normally generated by that action either.

Comment: Lots of moderaty things are currently randomly failing. Account deletion, the Stack Overflow flag dashboard, etc. Do re-try whatever you tried to do, it appears to be limited to a percentage of the server cluster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just retried a few minutes ago. Got the same error. I wonder if the initial cause of the bug actually went away but the server still mistakenly thinks something happened and that is preventing it.

Comment: Could be that the post metadata is now in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Update: I have now been able to move these to chat. I guess whatever was preventing this went away or was fixed by something else.

Comment: That is so weird. I just literally watched it work when you tried again.

Comment: Hah! I figured I'd give it a shot and whatdya know, it worked!